# Why does Gnome terminal only give access to SSH keys in the first tab of a window?

Tags: ssh, gnome-terminal, gnome-keyring

My SSH setup works pretty easy in XFCE4-terminal: the first time trying to log in to a server (from any terminal), Gnome-keyring asks for the passphrase for the corresponding ssh key in a popup window, and then accessing that server from any terminal would just work. It never needed any specific configuration for the graphical part, only the standard `.ssh/` stuff.

For some reason, on Ubuntu 22.04 with Gnome-terminal, this works only as long as I keep to one tab per terminal window. I.e., if I open a new terminal window and try to SSH from there, it works as it should. But when I open a new tab in that same window and try SSH from that tab, it asks me for the passphrase on the command-line, which is quite inconvenient since I tend to have a lot of tabs open and explicitly running `ssh-agent`+`ssh-add` in each of them is just tedious.

How can I find out why the "first tab" and "further tabs" cases are handled differently, and how can this behaviour be changed?

Comment: Looks like this bug: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-terminal/-/issues/253

Comment: @egmont indeed! In my case, `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` is missing in secondary tabs, I assume that's what causes the problem.

Comment: I don't know if it helps for this bug, but have you tried adding `ssh-add` to "Startup Applications" of your GNOME session? It will ask you for SSH key passphrase once when you log in to GNOME, and then should use that passphrase for every subsequent ssh request automatically. At least that's how it's working for me in Ubuntu 20.04.